# How can I get a array from a JS for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

There are two parts of HTML, i want get the hrefs from first part then use them for img src in the second part.

```js
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg'); 
for (let i=0; i <links.length; i++) {
    let classValue = [ ];
    classValue += links[i].getAttribute('href');

 myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv');
 for (let i=0; i<myDiv.length; i++) { 
     const myImg = document.createElement("IMG");
     myImg.setAttribute('src', 'classValue[i]');
     myDiv[i].appendChild(myImg);
 }
}
```

```html
<a class="myImg" href="1.jpg"> 1.jpg </a>
<a class="myImg" href="2.jpg"> 2.jpg </a>
<a class="myImg" href="3.jpg"> 3.jpg </a>

<div class="myDiv"> </div>
<div class="myDiv"> </div>
<div class="myDiv"> </div>
```

This code doesn’t work.

I think I don't understand JS for loop well, the result i get from first part - "classValue", looks not right.

I think "classValue" is not a array, so can't use it in second part.

How can i get a array for the loop?

Can someone explain this for me.

Comment: What was the intention of  `classValue += links[i].getAttribute('href');`? To add a string to the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get a NodeList of `.myDiv` elements. Do the same for `.myImg`, and iterate the NodeList with `NodeList.forEach()`. Take the href from each link, generate the img tag, and append it the `.myDiv` with the same index:

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.myImg')
  .forEach((link, i) => {
    const myImg = document.createElement("IMG");
    myImg.setAttribute('src', link.getAttribute('href'));
    myDiv[i].appendChild(myImg);
  });
```

```html
<a class="myImg" href="https://picsum.photos/100?1"> 1.jpg </a>
<a class="myImg" href="https://picsum.photos/100?2"> 2.jpg </a>
<a class="myImg" href="https://picsum.photos/100?3"> 3.jpg </a>

<div class="myDiv"> </div>
<div class="myDiv"> </div>
<div class="myDiv"> </div>
```

How to fix your code (see comments):

```js
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
const classValue = []; // define classValue outside of the loop, so you won't re-init it

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  classValue.push(links[i].getAttribute('href')); // push the items to classValue instead of concating them as strings.
}

// moved myDiv's handling outside of the links loop
const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv');
for (let i = 0; i < myDiv.length; i++) {
  const myImg = document.createElement("IMG");
  myImg.setAttribute('src', classValue[i]); // get the src from classValue
  myDiv[i].appendChild(myImg);
}
```

```html
<a class="myImg" href="https://picsum.photos/100?1"> 1.jpg </a>
<a class="myImg" href="https://picsum.photos/100?2"> 2.jpg </a>
<a class="myImg" href="https://picsum.photos/100?3"> 3.jpg </a>
<div class="myDiv"> </div>
<div class="myDiv"> </div>
<div class="myDiv"> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and the example, it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an array called classValue, to add an element to it you will have to do it as follows:

```
let myVariable = links[i].getAttribute('href');
classValue.push(myVariable);
```

although I am not too certain about this:

```
 links[i].getAttribute('href');
```

and then you can either loop through the array later using a foreach loop https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

or you can use a map in this format:
const name = "Chuloo"
const map = Array.prototype.map

```
const newName = map.call(name, eachLetter => {
    return `${eachLetter}a`;
})

// ["Ca", "ha", "ua", "la", "oa", "oa"]
console.log(newName);
```

reference: https://scotch.io/tutorials/4-uses-of-javascripts-arraymap-you-should-know